# Tweak graphics settings principal components

Tags: performance, counter-strike-global-offensive

How to tweak graphics settings in CS:GO? Which commands and settings are the most reasonable to change? I would not want to eek out every little bit, just get closer to an optimum in terms of frame rate.

How about screen resolution setting? A couple of years ago it made sense to reduce resolution, but I believe nowadays that is not reasonable since grahpics cards are geared towards working on the highest resolutions, right?

Comment: See my answer here, maybe it will help You:

http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/117776/cs-go-does-not-play-smoothly-with-a-1-gb-graphic-card/117877#117877

Answer (score 1):

I would like to answer your second question first: Yes, if your CPU and GPU are capable of, then running on a higher res would give you better performance.

However, with csgo in its current state, it is believed to have no configs/commands that really have an effect on fps, the best shot you have is tweaking around with settings in the video options and advanced video options.

Even the developers said it would be a better idea to upgrade hardware for better fps, instead of trying configs.

Answer (score 0):

I would say, instead of what you’d wanted, you can make your game smooth (will have the lag feel but it is in a stable form).

```
cl_showfps 1
```

Look at how much FPS you are constantly at. In the past, when I was using lousy graphic cards like Nvidia GeForce 2 MX 400, my FPS was only around 40‒60. So, no point setting `fps_max 101` (now is `fps_max` 300 for *CS:GO*)

So, what I did was `fps_max 41` (This makes your game run at 40 FPS all the way and this will be smooth. I use this settings for over one year, until I won my first competition, and then I upgraded to a better videocard.).

And also `cl_cmdrate 101`, `cl_updaterate 101`, `rate 128000` commands that you can find googling.