# CS: GO does not play smoothly with a 1 GB graphic card?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I am unable to play CS GO smoothly, even though I have an 1 GB ATI Radeon graphic card. I have tried to play against bots to see if that makes a difference, but it still has difficulty.

My notebook cofigurations are :

Processor Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2350M CPU @ 2.30GHz
Memory (RAM) 4.00 GB
Graphics Radeon (TM) HD 7450M
64-bit operating system
Number of processor cores 2
Network Adapter Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller
  Network Adapter Broadcom 4313GN 802.11b/g/n 1x1 Wi-Fi Adapter
  Network Adapter Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter
it dont even run smooth offline with bots !

Comment: the graphics card is not always the performance bottleneck. How good is your internet connections? your connection to the server you play on? your CPU? amount of memory? hard drive speed? operating system? More information is definetly required.

Comment: This cannot be reasonably answered with the information provided.  Once that information has been added, this can be reopened.

Comment: I've Edited and provided my notebook configurations ! now can u help me ? @ColinD @ fbueckert

Comment: @KamalKafkaesque Is CS:GO the only game that does not perform well? Have you tried turning down all the ingame graphic settings?

Comment: Considering you are on a notebook is it possible that the game doesnt use your dedicated grapics card and instead uses the one on the cpu ?

Comment: How many bots are you playing with? Try playing with less and see if it improves performance.

Comment: No  other games too doesn't play that gud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the console and enter the following command to display the FPS counter in the upper corner of the screen (by the way this is absolute the first thing You should do in any multiplayer FPS game)

`cl_showfps 1`

Now check the FPS counter while playing. See in what situations the FPS drops.

Go to the Video Options and set EVERYTHING to low, set the resolution to 640x480, now run the game in offline mode without the bots and see is there a difference.

To play in "casually" You will need to have at least 60+ FPS constant (but the gameplay will sometimes be challenging) for smooth play You will need to have at least 120+ FPS.

If You have low FPS when set everything to low - well, then Your PC is not good for this game, sorry, but when FPS are high - try to find a balance between quality and FPS by changing the resolution and quality of the game.